# Validation link does not work from gmail

Tags: php, validation, cookies, gmail, hyperlink

I sent the user a link to click, in order to validate his account.

Everything went right until I had the idea of testing it from a `Gmail` address.  As the user sends his request from the site, he 's already been obliged to choose a language which has been stored in a cookie.

I have `Firefox` as a default browser. It works with all other email clients such as `Yahoo`, `Hotmail` and `Windows Mail` but not with `Gmail`.

**The bug is that when the link gets clicked, a new page opens (as ever), but shows the cookie choice page and asks for choosing the language again and a again and again.**

This snippet is used to set the language cookie:

```
setcookie("language",$_GET["language"],time()+730*24*3600,NULL, NULL, NULL,TRUE);
```

Other cookies are set with the following rule on index :

`session_set_cookie_params(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE);`

A link in the following format is used to validate the user (modified):

http://www.example.com/index.php?%09%09page=validate&code=7c222fb2927d828af22f592134e8932480637c0d&user=some.random.user%40gmail.com&confirm=e34054aca67d77bb76fe62019ef331c7e2a0a4b9

It means a user having `Gmail` won't be able to authenticate.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: check that gmail isn't mangling the url in the email somehow. check your access logs and compare what's coming in to the server when that user clicks v.s. what you sent out in the email.

Comment: LinkedIn has this issue with Chrome browsers, to authenticate an email you have to do it through Firefox... I think the best solution would be to offer up a form where the user could copy and paste their codes if click through authentication fails. I've seen a lot of major sites doing this.

Comment: are the urls equal? I mean url when the script send email is www.site.com, but url in the email is site.com (without www or with folder, like www.site.com/somefolder/)

Comment: urlencode() outputs `%09%09` in the url that is sent.   What is it for ?   I found `%09` means "tab" what is it ?   Is not the cause of the Gmail failure ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the reason of this :

My code was indentated like this :

http://www.example.com/index.php?%09%09page=
validate&code=7c222fb2927d828af22f592134e8932480637c0d&user=some.random.user%40gmail.com&
confirm=e34054aca67d77bb76fe62019ef331c7e2a0a4b9

**This does not lead to a bug with any e-mail provider I have tested, except with `Gmail` !**

It inserts a **`%09%09`** after the `equal` so the autentication fails, because it does not reach the page it targets.

Hope this can help.